# Applying php.ini config, specifically upload_max_filesize, not taking effect after service restarts

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

Firstly, I have an nginx/php5/mysql server and I am trying to increase the upload_max_filesize to 5MB from the default 2MB.

I have read about this issue already on here, and I have followed the steps that others have mentioned: I have changed the variable in the global php.ini, and local php.ini and then restarted nginx, php5-fpm to no avail.

Furthermore, in virtualmin, the php configuration "assistant" there shows 5MB as you would think it reads the ini file directly.

I have run all the restart service commands from virtualmin and console to no avail as well.

None of these changes will take effect.

Thanks!

Comment: run` phpinfo()` what limit does it say, also check what php.ini file it says is running

Comment: phpinfo shows 2MB, and I am editing the php.ini file it is reading from.

Comment: Did you change both `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`?

Comment: reloaded server- still same details if its theright file then - well that makes no sense :(

Comment: Yes I have changed both, upload, and post_max

Comment: In that case, I would try looking at `phpinfo()`, specifically `Loaded Configuration File`. Next open up that file with some editor to check if the values are indeed changed. Restart nginx, php-5fpm services or if possible, restart the entire server. Just to be sure. Next make sure there aren't any `.htaccess` files interfering. If the problem still persists, something rly odd must be going on..

Comment: turn it off an on again (the server)

Comment: Send a ticket in to the hosting company.

Comment: How do you restart the php-fpm?

Comment: service php5-fpm restart

Comment: I mean your fpm restarted by what way? can you paste the command on here?

Comment: That is the command I used. "service php5-fpm restart", in the terminal

Comment: Oh, it's really weird, I think may be start your server is a fast way to locate problem , if the problem is still be there, will prove it's a configuration omission, if not, it's about reloadding config problem

Answer (score 1):

Had to reboot the server. Works now. Seems like this was the incorrect way to solve the problem, but for now, this worked.